# How to do partial search with Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I have a data indexed in Solr, like "S-1234567890".
If I try to search with full value it gives result.
But when search with 67890*, it does not work.

Can you please help, how to search the data when give partial text search?

Comment: What king of field are you using for this value? (e.g. string, text_general, custom?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using the below fieldtype for your field.

Field type defination

```
<fieldType name="text_ngrm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
```

You can define fields as below

```
<field name="name" type="text_ngrm" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You can also try to use below as well

```
<fieldType name="text_ngrm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         </analyzer>
         <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```